# Соединение с Oracle RAC через ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

Доброго времени суток!

Существует БД на Oracle, находящаяся на кластере. Подключаться к ней можно через 3 IP адреса, т.е. при установлении коннекта с клиента, следующее соединение должно быть через другой IP адрес (один из трёх).

Пишу приложение WinForms и с помощью ODP происходит коннект к БД. Для настройки соединения использую ODP Managed Driver, в котором, как известно, соединение может быть либо EZConnect (в котором можно прописать только один статичный IP, что в нашем случае не подходит), либо через TNS.

Насколько понял из документаций, существует возможность прописать tnsnames.ora таким образом, чтобы драйвер автоматически сканировал эти 3 IP и подсоединялся самостоятельно к рабочему. Прописал, однако драйвер меня не понимает.
Просьба помочь разобраться с проблемой.[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvckM.png)

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE не любит скобок. Проверь есть-ли скобки в пути к файлам ORACLE

Comment: Не понял, про какой путь идёт речь. Не могли бы пояснить?

Comment: + нет ли в тексте спец символов (при копировании из lync добавляются)